# Is react 18 problem in this form validation?

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks, tailwind-css, react-18

in form validation, I use Handel change and the problem is it does not show in input value and state change with a single value, and at the last validation in submitting it does not show answer
is it a problem for react 18 version...
**image**:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s1uvHR7LrDOh1Ud2_hBzuFXum-MWYBHh/view?usp=sharing

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        name: "",
        password: "",
    });

    function handlechange(e) {
        let { name, value } = e.target;
        return setData({ ...data, [name]: value }), console.log(data);
    }

    const onSubmithandeler = (e) => {
        let names = data.name;
        let passwords = !data.password.match(1);
        if (!names) {
            console.log("invalide name");
        } else if (!passwords) {
            console.log("password invalid");
        } else if (!names || !passwords) {
            console.log("all err");
        } else {
            setData(...data);
            console.log(...data);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ fontFamily: "roboto" }}>
            <nav
                className="font-lg w-full
 text-white flex font-bold justify-start bg-blue-700 sticky"
            >
                <h3 className="m-1 p-2">Ecomerce</h3>
                <h3 className="m-1 p-2">Login</h3>
                <h4 className="m-1 p-2">Register</h4>
            </nav>
            <div className="bg-gray-300">
                <div className="w-full h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
                    <form
                        onSubmit={onSubmithandeler}
                        className="w-full md:w-1/3 bg-white rounded-lg"
                    >
                        <div className="flex font-bold justify-center mt-6">
                            <img
                                className="h-20 w-20"
                                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/11/13/21/43/avatar-3814049_960_720.png"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <h2 className="text-3xl text-center text-gray-700 mb-4">
                            Login Form
                        </h2>
                        <div className="px-12 pb-10">
                            <div className="w-full mb-2">
                                <div className="flex items-center">
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        name="name"
                                        value=""
                                        onChange={handlechange}
                                        placeholder="Username"
                                        className="-mx-6 px-8  w-full border rounded px-3 py-2 text-gray-700 focus:outline-blue-400"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="w-full mb-2">
                                <div className="flex items-center">
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="Password"
                                        value=""
                                        name="password"
                                        onChange={handlechange}
                                        className="-mx-6 px-8 w-full border rounded px-3 py-2 text-gray-700 focus:outline-blue-400"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex items-center ">
                                <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    className=" m-2 p-2 float-right focus:outline-blue-400"
                                />
                                <a
                                    href="#"
                                    className="text-xs m-2 p-2 text-gray-500 float-right "
                                >
                                    Forgot Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                value="Submit"
                                className="w-full py-2 rounded-full bg-green-600 text-gray-100  focus:outline-green-400"
                            >
                                Log In
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem-solves if value-{data.[something]}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It looks like you tried to edit this with a different account.  That isn't going to work. There is no way to verify that two accounts with the same name are owned by the same person.  Edits from different accounts that add to an answer get rejected as "conflicts with author's intent."  Be sure to log in with the same login method you used when composing your answer to be able to edit it.